# How do I display a label in an edit box, but switch to password-entry mode when it receives focus?

Tags: delphi, editbox

I use Delphi 10 and Windows 10.

The following code makes caret and selection disappear in Edit1.

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Enter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.PasswordChar := '*';
end;
```

After the focus moves to the other control and in onClick it works well.

I can't use onClick because the focus moves by tab key and the Edit1 should start with default #0 because it holds text which is 'password' before the focus enters.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I can't make sense of this. Why would one setup the `PasswordChar` every time the control receives focus ? What is the motivation behind ?

Comment: @TLama i have edited the above about your comment. thanks.

Comment: `PasswordChar` is usually set in `FormCreate` or inside the `.dfm` file. It's uncommon to change it `OnEnter`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The edit control works as designed and as expected.

- If you want the control to hide a password then set then `TEdit.PasswordChar` in the OI or on creation or ... but not every time you enter the control
- If you want to have a **hint** then set the [`TEdit.TextHint`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit.TextHint) property which will be shown if `TEdit.Text` is empty and the control is not focused

Comment: FWIW, `TEdit.TextHint` looks like [this image](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQjZRJDrtc8x-ok92DN7u2vFfHVeQK3lCShSRTiCNJCR0g_eSe4OA).